# Scheduling events with changing Time zone

Tags: datetime, timezone

I need help with this scenario:

1) Currently it is summer time. I need to create a time interval for June 9 Monday 6 PM - 7 PM EDT and every week after that until end of  2018. This interval will be for students to schedule appointments with a tutor. The client right now sends that as a request for creating start time at June 9 Mondays *2 PM UTC*. (EDT is -4 hours offset) The server creates a start time in db for June 9 2 PM UTC and adds 7 days worth of milliseconds to create recurring

^ this causes an issue because of DST. Let's say it is right now November 5th (which is after daylights saving change). The DB still has Nov 5, 2 PM UTC saved as value. But because *my timezone changed*, instead of offsetting by 4 hours like I did on June, I offset by 5 hours. So the correct start time is "6 PM session in my timezone" becomes "7 PM my timezone". this is the error
the solution is either of one of two (or combination of both):

1)  instead of adding 7 days worth of milisecond, you add 1 week worth of miliseconds *depending on the user's timezone*  Currently, there's no way to extract a person's timezone based on utc offset (-400, which is right now in east coast USA, is also applicable to Canada, Carribeans, South America etc. We need to save a user's timezone as a string, rather than UTC offset count. There is an international standard for timezones)

2) ?? something else

Comment: There are a few widely used time zone databases, and they are supported by the major programming libraries/frameworks. It would be helpful for you to state which programming languages (or other envirionment) you are using.

Comment: I think the good solution is to store the user’s local time and his/her time zone. So for example 18:00:00 and America/New_York. Add 7 days in the local time zone and only after that convert to UTC if at all. This will even work if politicians change their mind and change the crossover date in the fall (as long as your time zone database is updated with the new date).